# Viewholder only binds images on scroll, not on initial load

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I have a recyclerView of images loaded with Glide, the size of each is generated programatically:

```
fun bindCommunityImageOffer(model: CommunityOffer) {

        val requestListener = object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
            override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, imageModel: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {

                return false
            }

            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean):Boolean{


                return false
            }
        }

        if (!model.mediaAspectRatio.isNullOrEmpty()) {


            val aspectRatioSplit = model.mediaAspectRatio.split(":")
            val widthRatio = Integer.parseInt(aspectRatioSplit[0])
            val heightRatio = Integer.parseInt(aspectRatioSplit[1])

            communityImageIv.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY


            if (widthRatio == heightRatio) {

                communityImageIv.layoutParams.height = communityImageIv.width
                communityImageCl.layoutParams.height = communityImageCl.width

            } else {

                communityImageIv.layoutParams.height = ((communityImageIv.width.toFloat() / widthRatio.toFloat()) * heightRatio).toInt()
                communityImageCl.layoutParams.height = ((communityImageCl.width.toFloat() / widthRatio.toFloat()) * heightRatio).toInt()


            }


        } else {

            communityImageIv.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP
            val widthRatio = 25
            val heightRatio = 21
            communityImageIv.layoutParams.height = ((communityImageIv.width.toFloat() / widthRatio.toFloat()) * heightRatio).toInt()
            communityImageCl.layoutParams.height = ((communityImageCl.width.toFloat() / widthRatio.toFloat()) * heightRatio).toInt()

        }

        itemView.communityImageCl.requestLayout()
        itemView.communityImageIv.requestLayout()


        Glide.with(itemView.context).load(model.coverUrl).into(communityImageIv)


        }
        }
```

RecyclerView in Activity:

```
private val adapter = FeedAdapter()

    private lateinit var emptyView: View
    private lateinit var progressBar: TintedProgressBar
    private lateinit var recyclerView: PlayerViewContainer
    private lateinit var refresher: SwipeRefreshLayout

    private var legacyOffers: MutableList<FeedItem>? = null
    private var offers: List<WatchAndRespondOffer>? = null
    private var communityOffers: List<CommunityOffer>? = null

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.f_sponsor_hub_my_offers, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        emptyView = view.find(R.id.empty_view)
        progressBar = view.find(R.id.progress_indicator)
        recyclerView = view.find(R.id.recycler_view)
        refresher = view.find(R.id.my_offers_refresher)

        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(OffsetItemDecoration(dip(30), dip(16)))
        recyclerView.setPlayerInitializer {
            PlaybackInfo(INDEX_UNSET, TIME_UNSET, VolumeInfo(true, 0.75f))
        }
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        refresher.setOnRefreshListener { refresh() }


    }
```

// Called on adapter after API call to add all retrieved items to RecyclerView

```
fun clearAndAddAll(data: Collection<Any>) { 


    items.clear()
    items.addAll(data)

    notifyDataSetChanged()

}
```

The images will not appear on the first time the list is loaded, but when the view is scrolled, new images will. The images that should have appeared immediately will also be loaded when I scroll back to the top of the list. I feel like I am doing something out of order but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Hi, I guess the adapter is not notified with the change of data which happened until you scroll it... you need to show some code of RecyclerView initialization and the adapter

Comment: Edited I'm calling notifyDataSetChanged() in the method above, which gets called right when the API call is complete